# Kendo ui filterable multi checkboxes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to write a piece of code that shows the options of a column as checkboxes for the user to filter.

But I wanna do more than that. Let's say for instance that the user checks the "USA" option in the example below, it should show as a result:  "USA", "USA1" and "USA2" (a contains filter).

I've found a variety of kendo filters but none of them could be applied to the property "filterable" - "multi:true".

I've tried the code on `http://jsfiddle.net/phqs/vfqs917w/` but I couldn't achieve the results I want.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
  field: "country",
  filterable: {
  multi:true,
  operators: {
  string: {
         contains: "Contains"
        }
     }
   }
 } ],
   filterable: true,
   dataSource: [ { country: "BG" }, { country: "USA" },{ country: "USA1" }, 
                 { country: "USA2" }
   ]
  });
</script>
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: You could have a list of checkboxes outside of your grid. Then once the user selects a country set a filter on the datasource and reassign the datasource back to the grid.  I made an update to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfqs917w/1/) as a small example of the idea.